# What is the correct word for the list of goods?

Tags: meaning

What is the correct word for the list of goods that we receive from our clients to be shipped(export) abroad?

> Please let me have your order/shipment list?

Answer (score 1):

It is called a "bill of lading" if the items are cargo to be shipped.

Comment: Also my answer.  That said, the exact term probably depends on the place (and time).  The proper term may be something else in New Zealand.  Or in the 18th century.

Comment: the term i am looking for is completely different than bill of lading,for instance i am an exporter, and we export the goods that required or ordered by the customer, and which word-term does refer to this list of goods to be shipped that i received from the costumer? something like shipping list or order list maybe?

Comment: Oh. As in "Thank you for your "order" Mr. So-and-so, we will contact you with availability and shipping dates? ("Order" is fine")

Answer (score 0):

Its sometimes called the packing list. If all items are to be individually listed it is often an advance copy/pro-forma invoice.

Answer (score -1):

[Manifest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_(transportation)).

"A manifest or ship's manifest is a document listing the cargo, passengers, and crew of a ship, aircraft, or vehicle, for the use of customs and other officials. **Where such a list is limited to identifying passengers, it is a passenger manifest or passenger list; conversely, such a list limited to identifying cargo is a cargo manifest or cargo list.**"

EDIT: Apparently I'm too new to comment, but from reading the clarifications above, the word you need is "order"; nothing more complicated is required.

Comment: The overwhelming majority of people who ever read your answer will read the most recent version. So please don't write "Edit:", which is only useful to the few people who happened to read it before you edited. Instead, please make your answer read smoothly to people who are reading the whole thing for the first time. In particular, if you believe that "Manifest" is an incorrect answer, please remove that from your answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I can see now that my answer was not sufficiently clear for readers, such as yourself, for whom English is not their first language. I will certainly not write "Edit" again in future contributions; your argument against this particular solecism cannot be refuted. However, if I 'may be so bold', I would suggest that your comment might be considered 'a tad harsh' (as we say in England), but I suspect it represents no more than a cultural misunderstanding (a misstep or infelicity) and evidence only of your own travails in 'getting to grips' with the language -- and the culture!